# Set JSP location for Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have simple web application based on JSP. Root of application looks like this:

```
|
|--META-INF
|--WEB-INF
|  `--web.xml
|--img
|--css
|--index.jsp
|--some1.jsp
|--some2.jsp
|--some3.jsp
```

Where web.xml contains lines below:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlet-jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet-jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Now I want change file structure of project - move all *.jsp files to special directory:

```
|
|--META-INF
|--WEB-INF
|  `--web.xml
|--img
|--css
|--jsp
   |--index.jsp
   |--some1.jsp
   |--some2.jsp
   |--some3.jsp
```

Can I configure "servlet-jsp" to process jsp/some1.jsp when "/some1.jsp" url requested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think many (all?) containers already map `*.jsp` (in any directory) to the JSP servlet, so writing such an explicit servlet-mapping is only necessary if you want to use custom file extensions for your JSPs.  To state it more directly: you can probably just remove the servlet-mapping you have written.

Forwarding requests for JSP files in `/` to `/jsp` might best be accomplished by defining a [filter mapping](http://javaboutique.internet.com/tutorials/Servlet_Filters/).   You will also need to write your own filter class.  Filters are a little like Servlets, but instead of generating content like a JSP or Servlet would, they are a bit more like a traffic controller, [re]directing requests.

Comment: Yes, just remove it. It makes no sense to duplicate the `JspServlet` in webapp's `web.xml`. Unless it's for some reason turned off on the servletcontainer (which in turn makes much less sense, I'd fix that first).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a servlet that is mapped to `/jsp/` then parse the path after the servlet mapping and forward to the JSP, using `request.getRequestDispatcer(targetJsp).forward()`

Answer (score -1):

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlet-jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jsp/*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I think this should do the trick.

Comment: I am under the impression that these patterns are not allowed. But let him give it a try.

Comment: @Bozho: it's possible. Don't have right now an environment to test this. But from [this document](http://www2.roguewave.com/support/docs/leif/leif/html/bobcatug/7-3.html), it should be allowed.

Comment: only `/path/*` and `*.ext` are. a combination is not, as far as I remember.

Comment: @Bozho is right. This is disallowed. Read the [servelt spec](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315).